# Proper way to join data based on coditions

Tags: pandas

[image]

I want to add a new column to a datframe "table" (name: conc) which uses the values in columns (plate, ab) to get the numeric value from the dataframe "concs"

Below is what I mean, with the dataframe "exp" used to show what I expect the data to look like

what is the *proper* way to do this. Is it using some multiple condition, or do I need to reshape the concs dataframe somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with left join for new column `concs`, if no match is created `NaN`s:

```
exp = concs.melt('plate', var_name='ab', value_name='concs').merge(table,on=['plate', 'ab'], how='left')
```

Solution should be simplify - if same columns names `'plate', 'ab'` in both DataFrames and need merge by both is possible omit `on` parameter:

```
exp = concs.melt('plate', var_name='ab', value_name='concs').merge(table, how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to test different ways to do "stack" and then different kinds of left, or inner "joins" but this works perfectly, and I split up the expression to see the 2 parts separately, made perfect sense when I saw it

Answer (score 1):

First [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the `concs` dataframe and then merge with `table`:

```
out = concs.melt(id_vars=['plate'],
                 value_vars=concs.columns.drop('plate').tolist(),
                 var_name='ab').merge(table, on=['plate', 'ab'
        ]).rename(columns={'value': 'concs'})
```

or just make good use of parameters of `melt` like in jezraels' answer:

```
out = concs.melt(id_vars=['plate'],
                 value_name='concs',
                 var_name='ab').merge(table, on=['plate', 'ab'])
```

Comment: thank you as well for the reply, I really like that stacking format, and extra credit for naming the parameter id_vars :)

I was looking at documentation but had mixed up pandas.melt with Datframe.melt which was one problem, and then I was confusing melt/pivot with stack/unstack when I now see they are not equivalent :)